# Azure ARM Template vnet connection

Tags: azure

I'm using ARM template to deploy my application and connect it to a VNet. I have 3 differents environments my template is working in dev, but i'm facing an issue in QA with a wierd error message

```
{"code":"DeploymentFailed","message":"At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/DeployOperations for usage details.","details":[{"code":"Conflict","message":"{\r\n \"status\": \"Failed\",\r\n \"error\": {\r\n \"code\": \"ResourceDeploymentFailure\",\r\n \"message\": \"The resource operation completed with terminal provisioning state 'Failed'.\",\r\n \"details\": [\r\n {\r\n \"code\": \"DeploymentFailed\",\r\n \"message\": \"At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/DeployOperations for usage details.\",\r\n \"details\": [\r\n {\r\n \"code\": \"BadRequest\",\r\n \"message\": \"{\\r\\n \\\"error\\\": {\\r\\n \\\"code\\\": \\\"InternalServerError\\\",\\r\\n \\\"message\\\": \\\"There was an unexpected InternalServerError. Please try again later. x-ms-correlation-request-id: 949b6663-5d2e-4b5f-b610-981ffc34ca75\\\"\\r\\n }\\r\\n}\"\r\n }\r\n ]\r\n }\r\n ]\r\n }\r\n}"}]}
```

here is the template

```
  "resources": [
{
  "comments": "Connect the resource into its subnet in the virtual network",
  "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/networkConfig",
  "name": "[concat(parameters('resourceName'),'/VirtualNetwork')]",
  "apiVersion": "2018-11-01",
  "properties": {
    "subnetResourceId": "[resourceId(parameters('vNetResourceName'), 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets', parameters('vNetName'), parameters('vSubNetName'))]"
  }
}
```

],

Any of you already had this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Seems to happen if the delegate to Microsoft.Web/serverfarms is not present on the subnet

Comment: Were you able to resolve the issue? If yes, please post it as an answer so it helps others in the community as well.